# Необходимо реализовать текстовый квест на php. Не понимаю как каждый раз выбирать из таблицы именно нужные строки

Tags: php, база-данных, html5, phpmyadmin

Понимаю, что id того, что появится на экране должно передаваться из кнопки, однако не понимаю как составить цикл, что бы каждый раз выбиралась из таблицы именно нужная строчка, и при этом что бы цикл не закончился раньше времени. Надеюсь я понятно выразил свои мысли)
Если вдруг поможет вот таблица
[image: Таблица]

php знаю только на уровне чтения, редактирования готового кода. Однако пишу по нему диплом) Так вот, как я привык выводить данные:

```
$link = mysqli_connect(... формирования подключение к бд)

$rez = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM quest')
Соответсвенно тут происходит вытягивание данных с базы данных.

Дальше цикл
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez){
echo $row['text'] . ' ' .$row['variant1'](Варианты должны быть 
кнопками)
}
```

По задумке после нажатия на кнопку будет открываться псевдостраница и передоваться нужный id, который покажет нужный текст и нужные варианты, но как это реализовать в цикле мне не хватает ума

Comment: По структуре кривовато, варианты скорее всего должны быть отдельной таблицей. А если в квесте понадобится 10 вариантов, будете добавлять еще полей, большая часть из которых будет NULL?  Ну и суть задачи не очень понятна, если честно. Скорее всего, вам нужно где-то хранить отдельно цепочку текущего квеста и выбранных вариантов, чтобы по ней находить продолжение

Comment: Изменил, теперь надеюсь понятнее что требуется)

Comment: Мне по сути, нужно хранить только id ответов, которые я буду выбирать в БД, и я не знаю как потом выводить именно этот вариант из таблицы. Ну а варианты исправлю так, что бы везде было по 3 и не было нулей